# Sorting Experience Profile results

Tags: experience-profile

This is using Sitecore 8.2.3. My client has concerns that their analytics data is not recording properly, but that appears to be due to the prolific amount of Anonymous contacts that are being recorded. It appears the search result list for Experience Profile is in alphabetical order by name.

Is there any way to sort the list differently, preferably by last interaction? Also, I'm not sure if they'd prefer to have anonymous contacts recording or not...I know in v9 anonymous contacts are off by default, is there a way to turn this off in v8 as well?

Comment: To turn anon off, The config file change for this is Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.config. The setting is <setting name="ContentSearch.Analytics.IndexAnonymousContacts" value="false"/>

Comment: And it should be ordering by the column "Last interaction", descending. So the last interaction should be at the top.

Comment: @ChrisAuer Good to know on comment one. On comment two, it definitely isn't sorting by last interaction...the first records it shows for Anonymous shows a last interaction of a year ago, but when I search for a name I see interactions from the last day. It's not pushing those to the top like I'd expect in a descending sort by last interaction. Maybe this should go to a Sitecore support ticket?